# SCSS has the color in rgba() format, but the color is in hex format. How to keep the color in RGBA() format in the genrated css?

Tags: css, sass

I have a SCSS file, here is one part of it. 
SCSS:

```
$red: 200;
$green: 200;
$blue: 200;
$opa: 1;
.th-layout-class{
    background-color: rgba($red, $green, $blue, $opa);
    padding: 10px;
    border-right: 1px solid grey;
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
    border-collapse: collapse; 
}
```

CSS:

```
.th-layout-class, th:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #c8c8c8;
  padding: 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid grey;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  border-collapse: collapse; }
```

Apparently, #c8c8c8 is rgba(200,200,200). 
But how to have #c8c8c8 in the rgba() format, so that opacity will be applied?

Thank you.

Comment: The opacity is 1, so it makes no difference whether it's expressed as a hex RGB triplet or an rgba() value. That said it would be nice if Sass didn't arbitrarily rewrite our units and values just because it can.

Comment: @BoltClock I changes $opa from 1 to 0.5, it works now. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the opacity is 1, it's equivalent to the hex format without any opacity.

As it says [here](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#colors):

> In compressed output mode, Sass will output the smallest CSS representation of a color. For example, `#FF0000` will output as `red` in compressed mode, but `blanchedalmond` will output as `#FFEBCD`.

If you use a different opacity, it will be forced to use the `rgba()` format.